# How to manually insert date time(not current time) without using carbon in php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I want to manually insert time to my data. Currently, I am using carbon to insert data. With carbon I can't *inject* date time manually since it is always using the current time. How can I do this ? Below are my controller :

```
public function userClockIn(Request $r)
    {
        $result = [];
        $result['status'] = false;
        $result['message'] = "something error";

        $users = User::where('staff_id', $r->staff_id)->select(['staff_id', 'date_checkIn', 'time_checkIn', 'location_checkIn'])->first();

        $mytime = Carbon::now();
        $time = $mytime->format('H:i:s');
        $date = $mytime->format('Y-m-d');

        $users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkIn = $time;
        $users->location_checkIn = $r->location_checkIn;

        $users->save();

        // Retrieve the current data
        $currentData = $users->toArray();

        // Store current into attendance record table
        $attendanceRecord = new AttendanceRecord();
        $attendanceRecord->fill($currentData);
        $attendanceRecord->save();

        $result['data'] = $users;
        $result['status'] = true;
        $result['message'] = "suksess add data";

        return response()->json($result);
    }
```

Comment: To clarify: "_... since it is always using the current time_" Carbon itself doesn't always use the current date/time, `Carbon::now()` does. You can use other Carbon methods though to create any data (`Carbon::create(1975, 12, 25, 14, 15, 16);` f.e.). Which data would you like to insert?

Comment: @brombeer I want to be able to insert a date time. I think i need to change this part, 

$mytime = Carbon::now();
        $time = $mytime->format('H:i:s');
        $date = $mytime->format('Y-m-d');
        $users->date_checkIn = $date;
        $users->time_checkIn = $time;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the answer to this question above. Thanks !

```
public function userClockIn(Request $r)
    {
    ..........

    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $date = $r->date_checkIn;
    $time = date('H:i:s');
    $time = $r->time_checkIn;

    $users->date_checkIn = $date;
    $users->time_checkIn = $time;
    $users->location_checkIn = $r->location_checkIn;

    $users->save();

    ............
```

}